# Step a counter if the label does not exist, print if it does

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, counters

I'm trying to label interviewees anonymously in sequence numerically, in a text I am likely to have to move around. When I refer to one with a label, I want to make a new step in a counter if the label does not exist, or print the previous relevant labelled count if the label does exist.

I have defined the following command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycounting}[1]{
    \@ifundefined{r@#1}{\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{#1}X\ref{#1}}{X\ref{#1}}
}
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
\mycounting{A} \mycounting{B} \mycounting{A} \mycounting{B}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, when the `\mycounting` command repeats, as in the example above, the output is "X3 X4 X3 X4" rather than "X1 X2 X1 X2" – as the counter does not stop stepping.

To clarify, desired output would be "X1 X2 X3 X1 X3" for

```
\mycounting{A} \mycounting{B} \mycounting{C}  \mycounting{A} \mycounting{C}
```

yet it is currently "X4 X2 X5 X4 X5".

Comment: You forgot the `%` at the end of the lines inside of the `\newcommand` to suppress unwanted whitespaces (but this is not the issue resulting in this numbering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the following does what you want:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcounter{mycountcounter}
\newcommand{\mycount}[1]{%
    \ifcsname #1@count\endcsname%
        X\csname #1@count\endcsname%
    \else%
        \stepcounter{mycountcounter}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname #1@count\endcsname{\themycountcounter}%
        X\themycountcounter%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\mycount{A} \mycount{B} \mycount{A} \mycount{B}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason, why the test with `\@ifundefined{r@#1}` fails is that the relevant label information is written to the `.aux` file as `\newlabel` at the time when `\label` is used, but `\newlabel` is not called actually, so `\r@#1` is not yet defined when `\mycounting{A}` is applied the next time, meaning the test will always be negative, i.e. the label is redefined again.

There's a small dirty hack to get rid of this problem: Say `\global\@namedef{r@#1}{}` after `\label{#1}`. The reading of the `.aux` file will define `\r@#1` again, as usual, at least two runs of compilations are necessary to get the cross-references correct.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycounting}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{%
    \refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{#1}\global\@namedef{r@#1}{}X\ref{#1}%
  }{%
    X\ref{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother    

\begin{document}
\mycounting{A} \mycounting{B} \mycounting{A} \mycounting{B} \mycounting{C}
\end{document}
```

[image]